# Password change enforced in web application with REST API backend

Tags: rest, authentication

In application I generate token to user if login and password correct.

But I have security policy about password changing in some period.

When password expires I need enforce user to change password, and block API (except login and change password endpoints) until he changed password.

What's other endpoints should answer in this case?

Answer (score 0):

My desicion:

Until password not changed endpoints (except user/login, user/chg-pwd) answer `403 Forbiddent`.